# Python: Reducing a set of strings

Tags: python, ruby, string, lambda

What's the equivalent of this in Python? This has been a nightmare for me to port over. I'm almost sure I'll need to combine lambda and list-comprehension for this situation. `@values` represents a string of numbers.

```
def summation
  @values.split(",").map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python:

```
>>> values = "10,20,30"
>>> sum(int(x) for x in values.split(','))
60
```

Ruby:

```
=> values = "10,20,30"
=> values.split(",").map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) 
60
```

Comment: I've tried something like this, I keep getting an error of ```invalid literal for int() with base 10:```. My string for the given object is ```"10,20,30"```

Comment: or `sum(map(values.split(','), int))` but your  answer is more "pythonic"

Comment: @kharandziuk It's `sum(map(int, values.split(',')))` :), and in Python 2 `map` will create an unnecessary list in memory.

Comment: What would happen if the string is empty? (In this case ```values = ""``` @AshwiniChaudhary I realized that my first test checks to see if the given string is empty, and if so, return 0.

Comment: @TheGrayFox `int()` will raise an error for empty string, what is the expected output for an empty string?

Comment: @TheGrayFox if you're worried about something like `"10,20,monkeywrench,30,40"`, you can do `sum(int(x) for x in values.split(",") if x.isdigit())`

Comment: It's expected to return 0 if the string is empty. That's why I'm receiving the error. That solved the problem @adsmith

Comment: @TheGrayFox To add to adsmith's comment, use `if x.strip().isdigit()` in case the string contains some spaces as well. For eg: `'1, 2,3'`

Comment: @TheGrayFox if you're specifically catching the edge case that the string is empty, just check for that first. `if not values: return 0`

Comment: `explicit is better than implicit` and all that.